# Design Pattern for PolymerJS

Tags: polymer

Currently i have seen many links and videos of polymer and I am very exciting about polymer but the only thing which keeps me doubtful is the performance problem with using polymer in current date for example if i import 5 external components with each one having a link to external css which means i have to make 5 http request for css files .So what design pattern should I follow to increase the web performance should I remove css links from imported components and concatenate all css files into one file and use on my main page.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes time to optimize for production, you can use the [`vulcanizer`](http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/concatenating-web-components.html) to concatenate imports and move your stylesheets inline, or perform various other transformations (e.g. forcing all JavaScript to be external for CSP).